# exclude list of words in the Regex search

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

root/element1/element2[@attr1='abc']/element3[attr3='xyz']/element4/element5[attr4='pqr']/element6/element7

i want to clear out all the attributes in the above xpath except the attr4. The expected output is - root/element1/element2/element3/element4/element5[attr4='pqr']/element6/element7

can you please help on this?

Comment: What's problem with your regex ?

Comment: Hint: Define a regex pattern that only matches all attributes plus brackets, but does not match an attribute whose name is attr4. If you have successfully defined this regex, use it in a call to Regex.Replace(...) to substitute all occurrences of attributes in your xpath with an empty string ("")...

Comment: this is my regex to match all attributes   \[[^\]]*\]     i want to know the way to include the exclude list in this pattern..

Comment: If you want only nodes which contain `attr4` then use xpath : `//*[@attr4='pqr']` You will waste lot of time coming up with a good regex particularly on any xml strings.

Comment: You cannot have an exclude list like you imagine. A regex pattern describes a continuous sequence of text matching this pattern.

Comment: i want clean the attributes in the xpath and leave the attr4, the attr4 would be dynamic string..

Comment: You can create a pattern that would match this exact line of text, but chances are you have a number of lines that you want a catch-all solution for. In which case, if you even manage to find a Regex that does it, it will likely be long and convoluted. With that said, your question strikes me as you looking for the answer to the wrong question.

Comment: @user845392 If all you need is `element5` which has an attribute `attr4` throw away your original xpath and use a new xpath : `//element5[@attr4='pqr']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below regex to match with all attributes which don't include `attr4`. Then you can directly use `Regex.Replace()` to get rid of all of these.

```
(\[((?!attr4)[^\]])*\])
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6j1E71/2)

Code:

```
string input = "root/element1/element2[@attr1='abc']/element3[attr3='xyz']/element4/element5[attr4='pqr']/element6/element7";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\[((?!attr4)[^\]])*\])");
var output = regex.Replace(input, "");
```

Output:

```
root/element1/element2/element3/element4/element5[attr4='pqr']/element6/element7
```

[Dotnet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bu1Udt)

Comment: Instead of creating the a new regex over and over, i need a help to make it compiled regex with parameter and then pass the value to the parameter (attr4 is passed at run-time) dynamically at run-time.